# Imagen en ios se descuadra

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

estoy realizando una app para dispositivos móviles con ios.
La cosa es que en la pantalla de splash quiero poner una imagen (UIImageview) pero dependiendo del modelo de iphone (simulador) la imagen se descuadra.
¿Como puedo hacer para que se adapte al dispositivo con el que se abre?

Un saludo.

Comment: creo que la solución a mi problema son las constrains.